# Find in the matrix the first row, in which all elements are arranged in descending order.

Tags: python, matrix

Find in the matrix the first row, in which all elements are arranged in descending order. Change the order of the elements of this row in ascending order.

For example: In this matrix the second array contains the elements in descending order

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [3, 1, -7], [8, -4, 9]]
```

the output should be:

```
[-7, 1, 3]
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You have to try to come up with the solution and if you're stuck, we will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all differences between the neighboring numbers in on row are greater zero,
print the row in reversed order:

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [3, 1, -7], [8, -4, 9]]
for row in matrix:
    if all(x - y > 0 for x, y in zip(row[:-1], row[1:])):
        print(list(reversed(row)))
        break
```

Output:

```
[-7, 1, 3]
```